# count values in column within range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe:

| Name | Age range |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5-12 |
| B | 12-18 |
| C | 11-14 |
| D | 7-9 |
| E | 17-22 |

I would like to get a count column where I count the number of people within the age range of the whole column

| Age range | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 5-12 | 2 |
| 12-18 | 2 |
| 11-14 | 1 |
| 7-9 | 1 |
| 17-22 | 1 |

Edit: the bigger age range must cover another age range for it to be counted into that age range as another person.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: You can use `.value_counts()` here.  See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html).

Comment: 5-12 range covers 7-9 range. do you want counting system consider this case as well?

Comment: @Rawson it seems to only count values and not the other ranges within it

Comment: @Yuri R yes I want it to consider that case that's why the count here for 5-12 = 2 and not 1.

Comment: Why `12-18` has `2` as count in the expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here is one possible option :

```
from itertools import permutations

s = (df["Age range"].str.split("-").apply(
    lambda x: pd.Interval(*map(int, x), closed="both")))

d = {l:r for l,r in permutations(s, r=2) if l in r} # or l.overlaps(r) ?

out = (s.map(d).fillna(s).map(lambda x: f"{int(x.left)}-{int(x.right)}")
       .value_counts().reindex(df["Age range"], fill_value=1).reset_index())
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Age range  count
0      5-12      2
1     12-18      1
2     11-14      1
3       7-9      1
4     17-22      1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but I got error TypeError: __contains__ not defined for two intervals. How do I fixe this

Comment: With your example, I don't get a similar error. Can you make an example that triggers it ? By the way, what's your pandas version ? I'm on [`2.1.1`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.1.1.html).

Comment: d = {l:r for l,r in permutations(s, r=2) if l in r}pandas/_libs/interval.pyx in pandas._libs.interval.Interval.__contains__()

TypeError: __contains__ not defined for two intervals

@Timeless this is the error it threw at me. I used 0.25.3. it's on another machine that I'm not admin of.

Comment: I see now why you're getting the error. Well, `0.25.3` was released in [October 31, 2019](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/whatsnew/v0.25.3.html).

Comment: now that I have tried to upgrade pandas it throws error InvalidIndexError: cannot handle overlapping indices; use IntervalIndex.get_indexer_non_unique

Comment: Can you make an example that triggers the error ? Otherwise, check *@sammywemmy's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77312693/16120011).

Comment: I couldn't use janitor. I have the same data as the example, just that there are some duplicates in age ranges. Could it be the reason? @Timeless

Comment: I can trigger the error if I add a row to your example `["G", "5-12"]`. What should be the final output for the whole df ? Can you update your post ?

Comment: I think that was the issue. but i had tiny dataset i just need to use some loops I think

Answer (score 0):

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) offers an efficient way of handling inequality joins:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

splitter = (df['Age range']
            .str
            .split('-',expand=True)
            .set_axis(['left','right'],axis=1)
            .astype(int)
)
out = df.assign(**splitter)
out = (out
       .conditional_join(
           out.assign(counter=1), 
           ('left', 'left', '<'), 
           ('right', 'right', '>'), 
           how = 'left', 
           df_columns = ['Name', 'Age range'],
           right_columns='counter')
      .fillna({'counter':0})
      .assign(counter = lambda f: f.counter + 1)
     )

out = out.assign(counter = out.groupby('Age range').counter.transform('sum'))

print(out)

  Name Age range  counter
0    A      5-12      2.0
1    B     12-18      1.0
2    C     11-14      1.0
3    D       7-9      1.0
4    E     17-22      1.0
```